# How do I not send infinite get requests to backend and still be able to render frontend dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern, react-hook-form

Somehow, there are non-stop requests going to the backend. I tried removing `requiredFields` from `useEffects`'s dependencies, but then the frontend stops re-rendering. I had to reload the page to render new values. How do I fix it? Tell me if you need backend code also to help.
[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import TitleForm from './TitleForm';
import DescriptionForm from './DescriptionForm'

const Course = () => {
    const { courseId } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [course, setCourse] = useState(null);
    const [requiredFields, setRequiredFields] = useState([])
    const [totalFields, setTotalFields] = useState(0)
    const [completedFields, setCompletedFields] = useState(0)
    const [completionText, setCompletionText] = useState("")
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/instructor/courses/${courseId}`, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                    }
                });

                if (response.status === 401) {
                    return navigate("/signin")
                }

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to fetch course data');
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                setCourse(data.course);
                setRequiredFields([
                    data.course.title,
                    data.course.description,
                    data.course.imageLink,
                    data.course.price,
                ]);

                setTotalFields(requiredFields.length);
                setCompletedFields(requiredFields.filter(Boolean).length);
                setCompletionText(`${completedFields}/${totalFields}`);
                setIsLoading(false)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching course data:', error);
                setIsLoading(false)
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [requiredFields]);


    return (
        <div className='md:p-6'>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-2">
                    <h1 className='text-3xl font-semibold'>
                        Course Setup
                    </h1>
                    <span className='text-sm text-zinc-600'>
                        Completed Fields ({completionText})
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-6 mt-16">
                <div>
                    <div className='flex items-center gap-2'>
                        <h2 className='text-xl font-semibold'>Customize Your Course</h2>
                    </div>
                    {!isLoading && <>
                        <TitleForm course={course} courseId={courseId} />
                        <DescriptionForm course={course} courseId={courseId} />
                    </>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Course
```

Comment: you are updating required fields inside fetch data and useEffect takes reuiredFields in dependency array that's the reason its going in infinite loop

Comment: The dependency list should probably be `[courseId, completedFields, totalFields]`.

Comment: If I don't put requiredFields or course in dependency array, then live rendering of new values doesn't happen. I have to reload page everytime on saving new values.

Comment: Maybe you could define a fetch function outside of useEffect and call it periodically with setInterval

Comment: @Billuc that just defeats the whole purpose of react. It should do everything by itself.

Comment: Lol why ? I may have not understood the question correctly, but you told us simply that you wanted re rendering with new values without hitting reload and setInterval runs a method (say fetch) periodically so you don't have to reload. Maybe you want re rendering on some event, but it isn't clear in your question. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Anandhu, I found a solution. Even though it might not be the "right way" but it works for now.

Course.jsx:-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import TitleForm from './TitleForm';
import DescriptionForm from './DescriptionForm'

const Course = () => {
    const { courseId } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [course, setCourse] = useState(null);
    const [totalFields, setTotalFields] = useState(0)
    const [completedFields, setCompletedFields] = useState(0)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const fetchOnSubmit = () => {
        fetchData();
    }

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/instructor/courses/${courseId}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                }
            });

            if (response.status === 401) {
                return navigate("/signin")
            }

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to fetch course data');
            }

            const data = await response.json();
            setCourse(data.course);
            const updatedRequiredFields = [
                data.course.title,
                data.course.description,
                data.course.imageLink,
                data.course.price,
            ];

            setTotalFields(updatedRequiredFields.length);
            setCompletedFields(updatedRequiredFields.filter(Boolean).length);
            setIsLoading(false)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching course data:', error);
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='md:p-6'>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-2">
                    <h1 className='text-3xl font-semibold'>
                        Course Setup
                    </h1>
                    {!isLoading && <span className='text-sm text-zinc-600'>
                        Completed Fields ({completedFields}/{totalFields})
                    </span>}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-6 mt-16">
                <div>
                    <div className='flex items-center gap-2'>
                        <h2 className='text-xl font-semibold'>Customize Your Course</h2>
                    </div>
                    {!isLoading && <>
                        <TitleForm course={course} fetchOnSubmit={fetchOnSubmit} courseId={courseId} />
                        <DescriptionForm course={course} fetchOnSubmit={fetchOnSubmit} courseId={courseId} />
                    </>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Course
```

Answer (score 0):

In your useEffect hook, you are updating the requiredFields with setRequiredFields for every successful fetch.  While you also include requiredFields in your dependency array, this is why there is infinite get request.

You should remove requiredFields from the dependency array.

Edited:
You may want to have a look into react query for live re-rendering.  You can dynamically control how your application fetch the data with various options, for example:

1. you can revalidate when there is an update detected (assuming you have POST/PUT request somewhere else), useQuery recognizes it by your given queryKey.
2. you can also set a refetchInterval, where it will refetch at this frequency in milliseconds

Installation: https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/installation

On useQuery:
https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery

A tutorial to start with:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yccbCol546c

Comment: If I don't put `requiredFields` or `course` in dependency array, then live rendering of new values doesn't happen. I have to reload page everytime on saving new values.

Answer (score 0):

> If I don't put `requiredFields` or `course` in dependency array, then live rendering of new values doesn't happen. I have to reload page everytime on saving new values - Prateek Kumar.

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77818571/how-do-i-not-send-infinite-get-requests-to-backend-and-still-be-able-to-render-f#comment137188896_77818571)  I believe that you want to get the updated values when you save the changes. For that, you need to have a callback function to fetch data after saving the new values.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  // get data
 };

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);

const onSubmit = () => {
  fetchData();
};

return (
  {!isLoading && <>
                    <TitleForm course={course} courseId={courseId} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
                    <DescriptionForm course={course} courseId={courseId} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
                </>
   }
)
```

Comment: It is working, but in this approach, I am getting `{completionText}` as `0/0` every time when page 1st reloads and then have to save something for it to change text like `2/4`.

Comment: For calculating `completionText`, you are accessing the state values updated in the previous line. Since **state updates are asynchronous**, you can't access the updated state value just after updating them. see more [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#troubleshooting).

Try something like this.
`const _totalFields = requiredFields.length;
 const _completedFields = requiredFields.filter(Boolean).length;
 setTotalFields(_totalFields);
 setCompletedFields(_completedFields);
 setCompletionText(`${_completedFields}/${_totalFields}`);`

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies are the values for which the hook should re-run when changed; if you set requiredFields in the useEffect hook, and it's a dependency of the hook, then the hook will always cause itself to re-fire! Usually, this is the effect of trying to do too much in a single effect, but sometimes it's unavoidable; in those cases, you would want to perform a value-equality check and avoid re-running the set of the value to be set is equivalent to the value already set. That isn't the case here, though.

You don't need to use state variables for `totalFields`, `completedFields`, or `completionText`, since you're not actually getting any value from reactivity on those values. They're purely derived from `requiredFields`. You can simplify your useEffect to just call `setCourse` and `setRequiredFields` from the remote payload, then compute your `completionText` separately from that. You can use `useMemo` to do it only when `requiredFields` changes, though it's likely a cheap enough operation that it's not strictly necessary. This has the added benefit of causing `completionText` to be correct if `requiredFields` were to be modified from any other callback, as well.

```js
const Course = () => {
    const { courseId } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    // course and requiredFields are set directly from the request data
    const [course, setCourse] = useState(null);
    const [requiredFields, setRequiredFields] = useState([])
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/instructor/courses/${courseId}`, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                    }
                });

                if (response.status === 401) {
                    return navigate("/signin")
                }

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to fetch course data');
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                setCourse(data.course);
                setRequiredFields([
                    data.course.title,
                    data.course.description,
                    data.course.imageLink,
                    data.course.price,
                ]);
                setIsLoading(false)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching course data:', error);
                setIsLoading(false)
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [courseId]);

    // When requiredFields changes for any reason, derive a new completionText
    const completionText = useMemo(() => `${requiredFields.filter(Boolean).length}/${requiredFields.length}`, [requiredFields]);

    return ...;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you take a look at WebSockets. They basically are open connections between your front and backend through which messages can pass, typically to send updates from the backend to the frontend.

I used ASP.NET SignalR as a WS library and I can only recommend it if you have a C# backend